# Sequence of the string day wise.

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

I have a function which gives me 12 digit strings.

For eg.

```
AA 01 201 210 22
AA 02 201 210 22
.
.
AA 99 201 210 22
AB 01 201 210 22
& so on. . .
```

---

```
public string GetPersonalId(int n)
{
    char letter1 = (char)('A' + ((n / 10 / 26 / 26) % 26));
    char letter2 = (char)('A' + ((n / 10 / 10 ) % 26));
    char digit1 = (char)('0' + ((n / 10) % 10));
    char digit2 = (char)('0' + ((n) % 10));

    string dateString = string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Today)
        .Insert(6, " ")
        .Insert(3, " ");

    return string.Format("{0}{1} {2}{3} {4}",
        letter1, letter2, digit1, digit2, dateString);
}
```

now the problem is that for next day this sequence should start again from AA 01 201 210 23.

can anyone help me.

Comment: what is the problem with the current code?

Comment: @w0lf current code works fine....
but for next day this sequence should start again from AA 01 201 210 23....how to do that...??

Comment: How are you generating the `n` that you pass in to the function?

Comment: @w0lf, I guess the variables 'letter1' and 'letter2' are not reseted to default values on day change.

Comment: @oded its an auto incremented no. which is generated each time new user is registered on our site..

Comment: Then why are you passing in the same number sequence at the start of each day?

Comment: okay...got it...thanks for your responses everyone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Wherever you're storing `n`, store a DateTime `dt` next to it.
- Every time you increment `n`, check if `dt` equals `Datetime.Today`

  - If so, pass on `n` as before.
  - If not, set `n` to zero (or maybe one) and set `dt` to `DateTime.Today`.

(I'd also pass `dt` into `GetPersonalId` rather than using `DateTime.Today` inside the function, just in case the date chnages between the two usages of `DateTime.today`.)

e.g. if you have

```
int currentN = 0;

...

string GetNextPersonalId()
{
    currentN += 1;
    return GetPersonalId(currentN);
}
```

change to something like

```
int currentN = 0;
DateTime currentDay = DateTime.Today;

...

string GetNextPersonalId()
{
    if (DateTime.Today == currentDay)
    {
        currentN += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        currentN = 0; // or 1
        currentDay = DateTime.Today;
    }
    return GetPersonalId(currentN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea is: each day you need to reset "n" value to 1.

Easiest way to make this function work as expected:

1. To keep last ID generated in previous day(-s) or to get it from DataBase; Main condition - the latest and not today
2. To pass "n" as difference between current ID and the one in step 1);